# Seting a function with NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations

I want to set a function `sg` which is a solution of the NDSolve based on a position `x`, time `t` and a combination of parameters `p1g p2g p3g p4g p5g` of the function `g(t)`.

But I got some error:

```
   rho = 2.7*10^3;
Cp = 1097.22;
k = 237;
rhocp = rho Cp;
g[t_] := p1g*1 + p2g*Sin[Pi*t] + p3g*Cos[Pi*t] + p4g*Sin[2*Pi*t] + 
   p5g*Cos[2*Pi*t];
opts = (Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
         "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}, 
         "IntegrationOrder" -> 5}}});
sg[vx_?NumberQ, vt_?NumberQ, vp1g_?NumberQ, vp2g_?NumberQ, 
  vp3g_?NumberQ, vp4g_?NumberQ, vp5g_?NumberQ] := 
 Module[{eqn, cc, prob, ctes}, 
  ctes = {p1g -> Rationalize[vp1g, 0], p2g -> Rationalize[vp2g, 0], 
    p3g -> Rationalize[vp3g, 0], p4g -> Rationalize[vp4g, 0], 
    p5g -> Rationalize[vp5g, 0]};
  eqn = {rhocp*D[T[x, t], t] + D[-k D[T[x, t], x], x] == 
     NeumannValue[g[t], x == 0]};
  cc = {DirichletCondition[T[x, t] == 0, x == 1/10], T[x, 0] == 0};
  prob = Join[eqn, cc] //. ctes;
  {T[vx, vt]} /. 
   Flatten[NDSolve[prob, T, {x, 0, 1/10}, {t, 0, 5}, opts]]]

sg[1, 1, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50]

InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {1.} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.
```

Comment: Try `Clear[g, sg]` first.

Comment: I think the first part of `eqn`, `g[t_] := p1g*1 + p2g*Sin[Pi*t] + p3g*Cos[Pi*t] + p4g*Sin[2*Pi*t] + p5g*Cos[2*Pi*t]`, evaluates to `Null` and isn't a differential equation.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

If you are going to use exact numbers or high precision in your calculations, none of your parameters can be machine precision.

```
rho = 2700;
Cp = 10922/100;
k = 237;
rhocp = rho Cp;
opts = {Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
       "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
         "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.001}, 
         "IntegrationOrder" -> 5}}}};
```

You should generally use `NumericQ` rather than `NumberQ` to test arguments for numeric values. `NumberQ` does not recognize symbolic numeric constants, e.g., compare

```
NumberQ /@ {Pi, E}

(* {False, False} *)
```

with

```
NumericQ /@ {Pi, E}

(* {True, True} *)
```

Numeric values for `x` and `t` cannot be passed in the call of `sg` **and** also have `x` and `t` used as variables inside `sg`.

```
sg[vp1g_?NumericQ, vp2g_?NumericQ, vp3g_?NumericQ, vp4g_?NumericQ, 
  vp5g_?NumericQ] := Module[{eqn, cc, prob, ctes, g},
  ctes = {
    p1g -> Rationalize[vp1g, 0],
    p2g -> Rationalize[vp2g, 0],
    p3g -> Rationalize[vp3g, 0],
    p4g -> Rationalize[vp4g, 0],
    p5g -> Rationalize[vp5g, 0]};
  g[t_] = p1g*1 + p2g*Sin[Pi*t] + p3g*Cos[Pi*t] +
    p4g*Sin[2*Pi*t] + p5g*Cos[2*Pi*t];
  eqn = {rhocp*D[T[x, t], t] + D[-k D[T[x, t], x], x] ==
     NeumannValue[g[t], x == 0]};
  cc = {DirichletCondition[T[x, t] == 0, x == 1/10],
    T[x, 0] == 0};
  prob = Join[eqn, cc] /. ctes;
  Flatten[NDSolve[prob, T, {x, 0, 1/10}, {t, 0, 5}, opts]]]

if = sg[50, 50, 50, 50, 50];

T[0.0012, 1.] /. if

(* 0.00788736 *)

Plot3D[T[x, t] /. if,
 {x, 0, 1/10}, {t, 0, 5},
 AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@
    {x, t, "\n\nT  "}),
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 MaxRecursion -> 5]
```

[image]